# Casting bounded wildcard to unbounded wildcard within a generic type is an error (X<Y<? extends T>> to X<Y<?>>

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, subtyping, unbounded-wildcard

Consider this sample:

```
private <T> void m(Class<? extends T> k, Set<Class<? extends T>> sk) {
    Class<?> ku = k;
    Set<Class<?>> sku = sk; // <-- Type mismatch: cannot convert from
                            //     Set<Class<? extends T>> to Set<Class<?>>
}
```

In other words, I can assign a `Class<? extends T>` to a `Class<?>` for some arbitrary `T` but not a `Set<Class<? extends T>>` to a `Set<Class<?>>`.

It probably has something to do with some limitation on covariance/contravariance, but what?

I could introduce a cast: `Class.class::cast` would do it.  But is there a way to bend the compiler to my will with subtle type-fu rather than bashing it in the head with a cast?

Comment: [nested wildcards](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Nested_Wildcards)

Comment: @Sotirios - now that I know the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32959018/7515790) I see it is a duplicate, but I didn't know it then and it isn't an obvious match to this question as it omits anything about nested wildcards, which seems to make it different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though a `Class<? extends T>` is a `Class<?>`, a `Set<Class<? extends T>>` is not a `Set<Class<?>>`, for the same reason that even though a `Dog` is an `Animal`, a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`.  Here, `? extends T` has the same role as `Dog`, and `?` has the same role as `Animal`.

You'll need a `? extends` in front of `Class` to get this to compile correctly.

```
Set<? extends Class<?>> sku = sk;
```